# iOS core data to-one reflexive relationships predicate

Tags: ios, core-data, nspredicate, entity-relationship, nsfetchrequest

I am developing a simple messaging app and use an entity keep relationship between replays. 
Have setup To-One reflexive relationship as follows.

[image: Reflexive relationship]

Now I am struggling to fetch all the reply in to a `NSFetchedResultsController` to display on a `tableview` (basically I need to display all previous conversations in a `tableview`). Could you please help me, how can I do this? Perhaps create a predicate which fetch all the related Memos.

Corrected entity layout.
[image]

Comment: Don't call it `relationshipMemo` call is `memos` (it should be **many** so give it a plural name). Don't call it `relationshipStaff` call it `author` (this is a **one** so give it a singular name). Remember that CoreData is not a relational database. It is an object persistence framework. So treat the entities like objects. A many relationship is just an `NSSet` so name it like you would if you were creating the models. You wouldn't name the `NSSet` `relationshipMemos` you'd call it `memos`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This model doesn't seem right.

- First, you should name the relationships to describe what they are pointing to.
- Second, all relationships should have an inverse relationship.
- Third, don't give your entity a plural name. Call it `Memo` not `Memos`. It will make everything easier.
- Fourth, don't use foreign keys in objects (like `staffid`) instead create a one-to-many relationship to the `staff` entity called `author` or something. With an inverse of `authoredMemos` or something.

This messaging app. Is it like SMS texting where only one person can see (and then reply to) each message? Or is it like Twitter where many people can reply to a message?

**SMS Model**

For the SMS type model you should have another entity something like `Conversation` that has a one to many relationship to the messages it contains. Then you can run a single query to get them all and display them in date order.

**Twitter Model**

For the Twitter type model you should have relationships...

- replies - [An array of Memo objects]
- replyTo - [A single memo object]

These should be inverse relationships.

Now if a user `replies` to a `memo` you can add it in to the `replies` array of that `memo`.

Comment: I am using Twitter Model. As you mention I have change the entity. I have updated my question to reflex this. Are you suggesting that I have create another two entities or keep two arrays?

Comment: @Chinthaka No, `replies` and `replyTo` are just relationships of `Memo`. They both point back to `Memo`.

Comment: so the replies is one-many and replyTo is one-one. Am I correct ?

Comment: The `replies` is many and the inverse `replyTo` is one. A relationship has two parts.